# Error message in Kivy using Jupyter: SystemExit: 1 and then # Before doing anything, ensure the windows exist

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, kivy, jupyter

I am an absolute newby and just completed a couple of tutorials to learn how to make a basic app in Kivy using Jupyter for Python 3. Every time I run the code, I get the following error message after these lines of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

I then do the traceback but do not understand a word...

---

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f8b60bf1a089> in <module>
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 2     PongApp().run()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py in run(self)
    827             self.load_config()
    828             self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
--> 829             root = self.build()
    830             if root:
    831                 self.root = root

<ipython-input-6-f93ce727e894> in build(self)
      1 class PongApp(App):
      2     def build(self):
----> 3         return PongGame()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    332     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    333         # Before doing anything, ensure the windows exist.
--> 334         EventLoop.ensure_window()
    335 
    336         # Assign the default context of the widget creation.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py in ensure_window(self)
    124         if not self.window:
    125             Logger.critical('App: Unable to get a Window, abort.')
--> 126             sys.exit(1)
    127 
    128     def set_window(self, window):

SystemExit: 1
```

Can someone please help out a newby? Thanks

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry for that! And thanks for pointing that out.